# Create flowsheet-like graph

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks

I'd like to create a graph that resembles a flowsheet in process simulation applications. A concrete example would be this graph:

[image]

I was able to recreate it by manually specifying the vertex coordinates:

```
streams = {"feed" -> <|{"From" -> "RefineryFeed", "To" -> "Mix"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "mixedFeed" -> <|{"From" -> "Mix", "To" -> "Flash"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "flashVapour" -> <|{"From" -> "Flash", "To" -> "RefineryProduct"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "flashLiquid" -> <|{"From" -> "Flash", "To" -> "Split"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "splitProduct" -> <|{"From" -> "Split", "To" -> "RefineryProduct"},
      "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "splitRecycle" -> <|{"From" -> "Split", "To" -> "Pump"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "pumpRecycle" -> <|{"From" -> "Pump", "To" -> "Recycle"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>,
   "recycleFeed" -> <|{"From" -> "Recycle", "To" -> "Mix"}, 
     "Class" -> "Product"|>
   };

flowsheetGraph = 
 Graph[Labeled[streams[[#, 2]]["From"] -> streams[[#, 2]]["To"], 
     streams[[#, 1]]] & /@ Range [Length[streams]], 
  VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> Large, 
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], 
  VertexCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {3, -1}, {3, 0}, {3, 
     1}, {1, 1}}, DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

Now I was wondering if there was a way to create a similar graph without manually specifying the coordinates. If I omit the `VertexCoordinates` Mathematica does a good job at selecting coordinates for the vertices, but it would be great if the appearance would be more "grid-like" like in the graph above.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using `"MultipartiteEmbedding"` as the vertex layout method, and perhaps adjust vertex partitions accordingly. Here is a stab at it:

```
graphData = KeyValueMap[Labeled[#2["From"] -> #2["To"], #1] &] @ Association @ streams;

Graph[
  graphData, VertexShapeFunction -> "Square", VertexSize -> Large,
  VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], DirectedEdges -> True,

  GraphLayout -> {"VertexLayout" -> {"MultipartiteEmbedding", "VertexPartition" -> {3, 3, 1}}}
]
```

[image: resulting graph with multipartite embedding]

You would probably want to re-order the vertices or partition them differently from what I've done here, but it should still be less work than explicitly setting vertex coordinates.

Note that I took the liberty of rewriting the way you obtained your graph data using explicit `Association` functionality, since your data structure was almost there anyway.

Answer (score 3):

A custom layout combining grid embedding and multipartite embedding:

```
ClearAll[multipartiteOnGrid]
multipartiteOnGrid[{r_, c_}, columnpositions_] /; c == Length @ columnpositions := 
 Module[{grd = Partition[Tuples[Range /@ {c, r}], r], 
   prts = columnpositions /. 
     {All -> r, i_Integer?Negative :> r + 1 + i} /. Span[a_, b_] :> Range[a, b]}, 
  Extract[grd, Join @@ MapIndexed[Thread[{#2[[1]], #}] &, prts]]]
```

The first argument gives the dimensions of grid and the second the positions in each column.

Playing with the two arguments of `multipartiteOnGrid` and the ordering of the vertex list in the first argument of `Graph` we get a variety of grid layouts:

***Examples:***

Using `graphData` from @MarcoB's answer and the list of vertices in the desired order in the first argument of `Graph`:

```
Graph[{"RefineryFeed", "Mix", "Recycle", "Flash", "RefineryProduct",  "Split", "Pump"}, 
 graphData, 
 GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
 VertexSize -> {.25, .1}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{3, 4}, {{2}, 2 ;;, {2}, 1 ;;}]]
```

[image]

With `VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{3, 4}, {{1}, {1, 3}, {1}, 1 ;;}]` we get

[image]

```
Graph[{"RefineryFeed", "Flash", "Mix", "Recycle", "RefineryProduct", "Split", "Pump"}, 
 graphData, 
 GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
 VertexSize -> {.25, .1}, 
 VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{3, 4}, {{2}, 1 ;;, {}, 1 ;;}]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
rg = RandomGraph[{16, 25}, DirectedEdges -> True];
Graph[Range[16], EdgeList @ rg, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
 VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{4, 6}, 
   {{1, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3}, {2, 3}, {2}, 1 ;;, 2 ;;}]]
```

[image]

```
ckt = CompleteKaryTree[3, 3, DirectedEdges -> True]; 

ckt1 = Graph[Range[13], EdgeList@ckt, ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, 
  GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
  VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{9, 3}, {{5}, {3, 5, 7}, 1 ;;}]];

ckt2 = Graph[{1, 5, 2, 7, 8, 3, 10, 11, 4, 13, 6, 9, 12}, EdgeList@ckt, 
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram",
  VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{9, 7}, 
     {{5}, {}, {}, {}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}, {}, {2, 5, 8}}]];

ckt3 = Graph[{2, 1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13}, EdgeList@ckt, 
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram",
  VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{9, 5}, {{1, 5, 9}, {5}, {}, {}, 1 ;;}]];

ckt4 = Graph[{1, 3, 2, 8, 10, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13}, EdgeList@ckt, 
  ImageSize -> 1 -> 50, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", 
  VertexCoordinates -> multipartiteOnGrid[{9, 4},
  {{5}, {5}, {3, 4, 6, 7}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}}]];

Row[{ckt1, ckt2, ckt3, ckt4}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]